# Two SSLContext in same JVM

Tags: ssl, jvm

We are receiving a SSL handshaking exception when another part of the code is calling SSLContext.getInstance().  Can someone please confirm or deny the ability to have multiple concurrent SSLContexts running in the same JVM using the same provider?  The method name getInstance implies a singleton.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple `SSLContext` instances, configured differently if you wish.

`getInstance(...)` is generally part of the *factory* pattern, not the *singleton* pattern, although a number of implementations of the singleton pattern also use the factory pattern to access this singleton.

In addition, `SSLContext.getInstance()` doesn't exist, only `getInstance(String)`, `getInstance(String,String)` or `getInstance(String,Provider)` (and having an argument on the `getInstance` method hardly makes sense for a singleton).

(Don't confuse this with `SSLContext.getDefault()`, which will always return the current default instance, although this can also be changed globally with `setDefault(SSLContext)`.)

Just in case you were talking about `SSLContext.getDefault()` instead, it's worth noting that the default `SSLContext` will only read and use the `javax.net.ssl.*` system properties once, the first time it is loaded. This could have consequences if you set these properties somewhere within the code, but not somewhere else (or differently) and call `SSLContext.getDefault()` in a different order: the first call to `SSLContext.getDefault()` wins (assuming you're not complicating this with further calls to `SSLContext.setDefault(...)`).

Comment: How can you have 2 different SSLContext of TLS in the same JVM though? For example they would use 2 different truststores.

Comment: @ben You can't have two different *default* `SSLContext`s, but you can certainly have two different `SSLContext`s and create different socket factories from them (and thus sockets configured differently).

Comment: for the same protocol? The problem is that SSLContext.getIntance("TLS") always returns the same instance, so how do you get 2 separate ones?

Comment: @ben Not sure what JVM you're using but if you call `SSLContext sc1 = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); SSLContext sc2 = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");`, `sc1` and `sc2` will *not* be the same instance.

Comment: I actually didn't even check it, my bad! I assumed wrongly that the name getInstance(protocol) meant some kind of static map behind. Thank you!

Comment: @benji I had that same confusion